# Comparator classes with fields

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

In a project where one uses a class which implements a `Comparator` Interface, in order to compare between some comparable objects I've noticed that I can design the class which implements the `Comparator<>` interface **with fields**, and then `Override` the `compare(...)` function and use the class's fields for the compare function logic.

so I'll have to call the sort function something like this:

```
Collections.sort(someArrayList, new SortClass(argument1, argument2));
```

My questions are:

- How common is doing something like this?
- Is it considered good design?
- Assuming I get a user input which should change the logic of the comparison between some objects, building a new wrapper class (with the given parameters) would it be considered as a better solution for that matter?

As requested my SortClass is (I generalized it in the above section but here is my real sorting class):

```
public class SortHouses implements Comparator<Hotel> {

    /** if house1 should be before house2 */
    private static final int GT = -1;

    /** if house1 should be after house2 */
    private static final int LT = 1;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public SortHouses(double latitude, double longitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(House house1, House house2) {
        double distHouse1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((house1.getLatitude() - latitude), 2) +
                                 Math.pow((house1.getLongitude() - longitude), 2)));
        double distHouse2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((house2.getLatitude() - latitude), 2) +
                Math.pow((house2.getLongitude() - longitude), 2)));

        if (distHouse1 < distHouse2){
            return GT;
        }
        if (distHose1 > distHouse2) {
            return LT;
        }
        if (house1.getNum() > house2.getNum()){
           return GT;
        }
        return LT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `SortClass`? There is no specific problem with doing this, but it's possible that you could build your comparator using `Comparator.comparing(/* based on arg1 */).thenComparing(/* based on arg2 */)` instead.

Comment: Why don't you just implement `comparable` in your class?

Comment: You can also do that without using your own class. Using `Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>).thenComparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>)`.

Comment: @HusamBdr Since the class might not contain a natural ordering of its elements. Consider a class `Car`, which an `EngineSorter`.

Comment: @HusamBdr I have no access to the class as part of my exercise.

Comment: @HusamBdr Comparable is for **natural ordering only**. It is not just an "easier" Comparator. If I have a class `Person` and I want to sort them by name, it does not make sense to implement Comparable. People are not ordered **naturally** by name, or indeed by any other criteria.

Comment: @AndyTurner I added that to my original post, also note the constructor which feels a bit weird in a sorting class idk....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How common doing something like this is?

A parameterised Comparator? Not very common. Usually things are sorted with regards to their own properties.

> Is it considered a good design?

Yes, if you want to sort locations by distance to a reference location, then using a parameterised Comparator seems like a good way to accomplish this.

However, I can see one thing I don't like. Your `SortHotelsByProximity` is actually doing a "secret" comparison with POI (points of interest?) in case of a draw.

It would be clearer, and give you more flexibility later, if you were to move this logic into a second Comparator: `SortHotelsByPOI`. You can combine Comparators together to account for draws with the method [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-), which would look something like this:

```
hotels.sort(new SortHotelsByProximity().thenComparing(new SortHotelsByPOI()))
```

> Assuming I get a user input which should change the logic of the
>   comparison between some objects, building a new wrapper class (with
>   the given parameters) would be considered as a better solution for
>   that matter?

I don't know what you mean by 'wrapper class', but building a comparator dynamically based upon user input is fine, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: by "wrapper class" I mean, building a new Object which include the old object as a first field and the parameter (say "user Input") as a second field, which will result in all the object in the array with the same second field, which is again a bit weird for me, I'm confused.

Comment: @MercyDude Still not clear. In terms of your hotel example, what would you do?

Comment: Ok let me explain, I was requested to sort an array of hotels from a given (user given) geographic point, also the Hotel object cannot be changed therefor I have to manipulate this in some (presumably) esoteric ways.

Comment: @MercyDude I think we're on the same page. So you get a user input lat/long and then create a Comparator based upon that input? Nothing wrong with that. I've edited my answer to show one potential improvement I would make, by the way.

Comment: Use [hypotenuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse)  as `double distHouse1 = Math.hypot(house1.getLatitude() - latitude, house1.getLongitude() - longitude);`

Comment: @JoopEggen If we're optimising that, there is no point in even doing the square root. Since we only care about relative distances rather than absolute, you can just compare C²

Comment: @Michael `hypot` is a native function (there is also a C hypot), which can utilize the FPU. But I do not know which is faster because of the square root; the original code was too verbose. Being aware of `hypot` can shorten code and make it more readable.